# Table display issue, only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

I really don't know how to deal with this, the table works fine on Firefox/IE

See : 
[image: tablefire/ie]

on chrome : 
[image: tablechrome]

here is the actual css of the table

```
table {
padding: 24px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 550px;   
}
```

td#tadmin

```
td#tabmin {
width: 30px;
height: auto;
float: left;
font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

tried

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

do not work.

As asked, I display the table in php using echo:

```
echo "<table style='padding:24px;margin:0 auto;width:550px;'>".  
  "<tr>".
     "<td id=tabmin  >".
     "<div class=tabminscale style=text-align:center;>"
     .$row['min']."'"."</div>". 
     "</td>".
       "<td id=tabcom >" .
       "<div id=commentaires>".
       $row['commentaire']."</br>".
       "</td>".
"</tr>".
</div>";
```

Comment: can you provide some html?

Comment: `"<div id=commentaires>".` does not look like it is closed properly.

Comment: Well, you markup is invalid.

Comment: i'm not zoomed out on chrome, if the div is not closed properly shouldn't the bug appear on Firefox/ie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is [invalid](http://s13.postimg.org/kdvkso26v/Untitl1ed.png). Always check you markup with [validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

So, if you remove the PHP stuff, you'll get:

```
<table style='padding:24px;margin:0 auto;width:550px;'>
    <tr>
        <td id=tabmin>
            <div class=tabminscale style=text-align:center;>foo</div>
        </td>
        <td id=tabcom>
            <div id=commentaires>bar</br> <!-- invalid closing for br tag -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    </div> <!-- wrong -->
    <!-- where's </table>? -->
    <!-- also add quotes to HTML Attributes-->
```

Change it to:

```
<table style='padding:24px;margin:0 auto;width:550px;'>
    <tr>
        <td id='tabmin'>
            <div class='tabminscale' style='text-align:center;'>foo</div>
        </td>
        <td id='tabcom'>
            <div id='commentaires'>bar<br/></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```